# AWS Java: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Bad file descriptor

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to follow SQS example from this repo https://github.com/jonyfs/spring-boot-jms-sqs.
I have upgraded Spring boot to 2.1.0-RELEASE and cloud dependency to Greenwich.M1. The code is working fine, producing messages and consuming it
But I keep getting below exception. I have tried with different dependencies combinations and adding clientconfiguration also.

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443 [sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/52.119.165.100] failed: Bad file descriptor (connect failed)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1116)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1066)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2033)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2009)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeGetQueueUrl(AmazonSQSClient.java:1084)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.getQueueUrl(AmazonSQSClient.java:1060)
    at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.getQueueUrl(AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.java:280)
    at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.getQueueUrl(AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.java:251)
    at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSSession.createQueue(SQSSession.java:622)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveQueue(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:85)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveDestinationName(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:59)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.resolveDestinationName(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.createListenerConsumer(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:222)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.initResourcesIfNecessary(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1216)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1188)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443 [sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/52.119.165.100] failed: Bad file descriptor (connect failed)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy77.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1238)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1058)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Bad file descriptor (connect failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:339)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

`Bad file descriptor` are usually thrown when you use a closed socket. Typically AWS SDK will automatically retry connection errors like this, which is why you're not seeing any actual impact - on the retry it uses a fresh connection.

If they're happening once in a while, just ignore them. If they happen frequently, try playing with your connection settings in the ClientConfiguration to see what reduces them.

I also strongly suggest validating that you don't have some sort of classpath conflict where there are multiple versions of the same classes on your classpath - "interesting" things can happen at runtime due to how the classloader chooses which one to use.